# Symfony3 absolute path to excel file for import

Tags: excel, symfony

I have to import content of some excel-files into database, which are selected from usb-stick or some other location. I generate the inputs (type=file) dynamically in for loop and can select the excel-files for each row. After click on import-button I want to insert selected file in my controller action into the db. How can i get the full/absolute path to selected file?? I just get Fakepath+Excel-Filename. Or what is the best way to get real path to some file? Thanks a lot

Comment: You mean the absolute path of the file on your server? like `/var/www/myApp/web/uploads/excels/myfile_uploaded.xlsx`?

Comment: i mean even local machine, no the server: C:\UserX\Desktop\test.xls or D:\SomeDirectory\text.xls

Comment: ps: the file dont should be uploaded - the content of file should be inserted into db and thats it...

Comment: You can't know where the file comes from. (and you shouldn't care). What are you trying to do with that particular information? You don't need it to extract the data of a file

Comment: i need to extract the data from a file:
- i need the rows from excel_1.xls in new generated table (used later as template) for one record xy from permanent table
- i need the rows from excel_2.xls in new generated table (used later as template)  for other record yz
- then i need this two new generated tables in one new table (which contains some additional attributes ) 

i dont need the excel files to upload, just the row content of them, and there are really many rows, but i need them in the database!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getClientOriginalName` method on uploaded file (https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName)

similar post: [how to get the path of a file upload and save in db using symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727723/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-file-upload-and-save-in-db-using-symfony2)

Comment: Thank you, but i dont want to upload the file! I want to read the file with PHPOffice / PHPExcel and insert rows into db, not the excel-file. And for this purpose i need the path, but not from the app, like this:
 $inputFileName = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/excel/testempty.xlsx';

Comment: I think that for security reasons, this is forbidden (even in javascript).

Comment: Mhh, okay, i see, but it should be possible to get path with php somehow in controller??  Its not the best solution to copy everytime the excel-files into the app directory :(

Comment: best practice is to use `Form`. Upload, process files, and then delete them (doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Romain Norsberg 's answer:

[The documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) show you how to upload a file, but if you just want to exploit it's content you can do it whitout saving the file!

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // $file stores the uploaded PDF file
        /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $product->getBrochure();

        //  do whatever you want to do with the content of the file without saving the file in the server

        //something like
        $contents = file_get_contents($file->getPathname()); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This what you can do

```
 if($request->isMethod('post')) {
        // retrieve the uploaded file
        $file = $request->files->get('inputExcel');
        // retrieve the web directory path
        $webDir = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir() . "/web";
        //Move the file in your web directory
        $file->move($webDir, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $pathFile = $webDir.'/'. $file->getClientOriginalName();
        //call your service to save data from file
        $saveDataFromFile->($pathFile);
        //remove the file after treatment
        unlike($pathFile);
}
```